# How does the closure work in the method mapValues?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, plist

I'm trying to understand this how the [mapValues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995348-mapvalues) method works in the following code from [Calendar Heatmap](https://github.com/Zacharysp/CalendarHeatmap/blob/master/Example/CalendarHeatmap/ViewController.swift).

1. First, a function loads a dictionary:

```swift
private func readHeatmap() -> [String: Int]? {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "heatmap", withExtension: "plist") else { return nil }
    return NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) as? [String: Int]
}
```

[heatmap.plist](https://github.com/Zacharysp/CalendarHeatmap/blob/master/Example/CalendarHeatmap/heatmap.plist) is a key/value list like this:

```
    <key>2019.5.3</key>
    <integer>3</integer>
    <key>2019.5.5</key>
    <integer>4</integer>
    <key>2019.5.7</key>
    <integer>3</integer>
```

2. A property is initialized using the above function:

```swift
lazy var data: [String: UIColor] = {
    guard let data = readHeatmap() else { return [:] }
    return data.mapValues { (colorIndex) -> UIColor in
        switch colorIndex {
        case 0:
            return UIColor(named: "color1")!
        case 1:
            return UIColor(named: "color2")!
        case 2:
            return UIColor(named: "color3")!
        case 3:
            return UIColor(named: "color4")!
        default:
            return UIColor(named: "color5")!
        }
    }
}()
```

3. Finally, the `data` property defined above is used in the following function:

```swift
func colorFor(dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UIColor {
    guard let year = dateComponents.year,
        let month = dateComponents.month,
        let day = dateComponents.day else { return .clear}
    let dateString = "\(year).\(month).\(day)"
    return data[dateString] ?? UIColor(named: "color6")!
}
```

Apple's documentation states that `mapValues` returns a dictionary "containing the keys of this dictionary with the values transformed by the given closure."

My questions is, what exactly is the value `colorIndex` passed into the closure in `data.mapValues { (colorIndex) -> UIColor in`? Is it from `heatmap.plist`? I'm confused how a `String` is passed into `date`, date[dateString] from the `colorFor(dateComponents: )` function, but `colorIndex` is Int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally, `data` is like this:

```
"2019.5.3" : 3
"2019.5.5" : 4
"2019.5.7" : 3
```

Suppose you did `data.mapValues(f)`, where `f` is a function, the resulting dictionary will look like this:

```
"2019.5.3" : f(3)
"2019.5.5" : f(4)
"2019.5.7" : f(3)
```

So now, the value type of the dictionary changes to the return type of `f`, while the key type remains unchanged.

> what exactly is the value `colorIndex` passed into the closure?

It's every value in `data`. Every value will be passed into closure once.

To see this more clearly, I've written one possible way that `mapValues` could be implemented:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func myMapValues<T>(_ transform: (Value) throws -> T) rethrows -> [Key: T] {
        var retVal = [Key: T]()
        for entry in self {
            retVal[entry.key] = try transform(entry.value)
        }
        return retVal
    }
}
```

> Is it from heatmap.plist?

Indirectly, yes. The contents of the local variable `data` (the `[String: Int]`) was originally from `heatmap.plist`, but `mapValues` operates directly on the `data` already read from the file.

> I'm confused how a String is passed into `data`, `data[dateString]` from the `colorFor(dateComponents: )` function, but `colorIndex` is `Int`.

`colorIndex` is irrelevant here. `colorIndex` is simply the name of the function parameter of the function that you pass to `mapValues`. `mapValues` has been called at this point, and the dictionary's values have been transformed.

You can pass a `String` into `data` because the `data` dictionary has `String`s as keys. Recall that `mapValues` doesn't change the key type. Note that this `data` is different from the local variable `data`. I'm talking about the `lazy` property `data`, of type `[String: UIColor]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this mean the original `[key: value]` is transformed from something like `"2019.5.5" : 4` to `"2019.5.5" : UIColor(named: "color5")`? If the purpose of the `data` property here is to enter a some subscript, `data[dateString]`, and return a corresponding `UIColor`, I'm not sure what the `plist` here is for.

Comment: @Kevvv Re: your first question, yes. Re: "I'm not sure what the plist here is for." The plist is to provide late binding. Sure, you could just hardcode the `[String: UIColor]` dictionary in the source code, but to change its contents you'd have to recompile again. Putting the data in a file makes it easy to make changes.

Comment: You can simply return `try .init(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(keys, values.map(transform)))`

Comment: Is it correct to say that the order of the operation is 1) write to plist `"2020.8.3" : 3` 2) The dictionary gets transformed to the according colour `"2020.8.3" :UIColor(named: "color4")` and 3) `data["2020.8.3"]`

Comment: @Kevvv Step 1 should be **read** the dictionary from plist. Also note that since `data` is lazy, steps 1 and 2 will only be done once, but step 3 is done every time `colorFor` is called.